# ubuntu-touch for OnePlus One lockscreen problems

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I recently used Magic Device Tool to flash my OnePlus One with Ubuntu Touch. Things work just fine, until I lock the screen. After that I can't unlock the phone. I press the power button, and nothing happens. When I press the power button a second time, the screen just flashes ever so briefly. I end up having to reboot the phone just to use it again.
Thank you in advance for any help! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

magic-device-tool dev here. 
Please try the devel_rc-proposed channel. The power button but is a known issue on the stable channel and should be fixed by now in devel_rc-proposed.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)